# Optim() function vary by decimals?

Tags: r

The par argument in the `optim()` function vary  in decimals? If not how to do this? in the code below i set lower= 0 and upper =1, does that mean it will vary from 0 to 1 by 1 or from 0 to 1 by 0.01?

```r
wacc2<-function(percentage_own_capital,free_risk_rate,bank_rate,taxes){
   percentage_own_capital*(free_risk_rate) +
      (1-percentage_own_capital) * bank_rate*(1-taxes) 
   
}
optim(0, wacc2,  free_risk_rate=0.065,bank_rate=0.08,taxes=0.30,upper=1,lower=c(0))$par
```

Comment: I don't understand... could you please say a little more about what you are currently getting and what your goal is? We can't run the code you show to try/see because we don't have any of your data...

Comment: Can you be more clear? Do you need more precision? What output are you getting and what is the expected output?

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: I don't know where your `0.01` idea comes from. It is lower and upper bounds. The optimization called by `optim` will control the step size based on the estimated gradient - it is not a grid search.

Comment: @GregorThomas there is no need of data here, i'm finding which value of percentage_own_capital that minimizes the function wacc2 with free_risk_rate=0.065, bank_rate=0.08, taxes=0.30.

Comment: Well, data is often the best way to understand a confusingly worded question. Before you clarified, I thought perhaps if I could run your code it would become apparent what your question meant.

Answer (score 0):

What can be varied in `optim` are the absolute and relative convergence tolerances. This is set in argument `control`, a named list with optional members `abstol` and `reltol`. From `help('optim')`:

> reltol
> Relative convergence tolerance. The algorithm stops if it is
> unable to reduce the value by a factor of reltol * (abs(val) + reltol)
> at a step. Defaults to sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), typically about
> 1e-8.

All three calls below give the same result. I have added one call to `optimise`, since, also from the documentation, method `"Nelder-Mead"` is unreliable for one-dimensional problems and the suggested method for these problems is `"Brent"`, which calls `optimise`.

```
wacc2 <- function(percentage_own_capital, free_risk_rate, bank_rate, taxes){
  percentage_own_capital * free_risk_rate +
    (1 - percentage_own_capital) * bank_rate * (1 - taxes) 
}

optim(0, wacc2, 
      free_risk_rate = 0.065,
      bank_rate = 0.08,
      taxes = 0.30,
      method = "Brent",
      lower = 0, upper = 1)$par
optim(0, wacc2, 
      free_risk_rate = 0.065,
      bank_rate = 0.08,
      taxes = 0.30,
      method = "Brent",
      control = list(reltol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5),
      lower = 0, upper = 1)$par
optimise(wacc2,
         interval = c(0, 1),
         free_risk_rate = 0.065,
         bank_rate = 0.08,
         taxes = 0.30,
         tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)$minimum
#[1] 6.474096e-09
```

Also note that if the gradient is passed, the results are still the same.

```
grwacc2 <- function(percentage_own_capital, free_risk_rate, bank_rate, taxes){
  free_risk_rate - bank_rate*(1 - taxes)
}

optim(0, wacc2, grwacc2,
      free_risk_rate = 0.065,
      bank_rate = 0.08,
      taxes = 0.30,
      method = "Brent",
      control = list(reltol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5),
      lower = 0, upper = 1)$par
#[1] 6.474096e-09
```